# function called in main() funcion isn't updating global variables' values

Tags: python, function

I defined the function 'actualizar_contadores()' and when called inside the main() function, its supossed to update the values of all the variables that were defined at the beginning of the script. First I didnt pass the actual variables as parameters to the function but that resulted in a "local variable referenced before assignment" error. Then I passed the references as parameters and that problem was gone but when I wanted to see the results they werent updated. I tried returning a tuple and assigning it to the variables in order to update their values, but it isnt working either and I get the local variable referenced before assignment error again. What can I do?

````
cant_motos = cant_autos = cant_camiones = 0
recaudacion_total = recaudacion_efectivo = recaudacion_telepeaje = 0
pasadas_primera_hora = pasadas_segunda_hora = pasadas_tercera_hora = pasadas_cuarta_hora = 0
cont_efectivo = cont_telepeaje = 0
patente_actual = ""
patente_nueva = ""


def actualizar_contadores(vehiculo, forma_de_pago, cant_motos,
                          cant_autos, cant_camiones,recaudacion_efectivo,
                          recaudacion_telepeaje,cont_efectivo,cont_telepeaje):
    if vehiculo == "Moto":
        cant_motos += 1
        if forma_de_pago == 1:
            recaudacion_efectivo += 20
            cont_efectivo += 1
        elif forma_de_pago== 2:
            recaudacion_telepeaje += 20
            cont_telepeaje += 1

    elif vehiculo == "Auto":
        cant_autos += 1
        if forma_de_pago == 1:
            recaudacion_efectivo += 40
            cont_efectivo += 1
        elif forma_de_pago == 2:
            recaudacion_telepeaje += 40
            cont_telepeaje += 1

    elif vehiculo == "Camion":
        cant_camiones += 1
        if forma_de_pago == 1:
            recaudacion_efectivo += 80
            cont_efectivo += 1
        elif forma_de_pago == 2:
            recaudacion_telepeaje += 80
            cont_telepeaje += 1



def main():

    # menu principal
    opcion = pedir_opcion(menu_principal, 4)
    while opcion != 4:
        while opcion != 3:
            if opcion == 1:
                carga = pedir_opcion(menu_ingreso_datos, 2)
                print("Ingrese la siguiente operacion: ")
                opcion = pedir_opcion(menu_principal, 4)

            elif opcion == 2:
                if carga == 1:
                    diferencia = 0
                    tiempo_inicial = time.time()
                    while diferencia < 32:
                        contar_pasadas(diferencia, pasadas_primera_hora,
                                        pasadas_segunda_hora,
                                        pasadas_tercera_hora,
                                        pasadas_cuarta_hora)

                        tipo_vehiculo = pedir_opcion(menu_vehiculos, 3)
                        if tipo_vehiculo == 1:
                            vehiculo = "Moto"
                        elif tipo_vehiculo == 2:
                            vehiculo = "Auto"
                        elif tipo_vehiculo == 3:
                            vehiculo = "Camion"

                        forma_de_pago = pedir_opcion(menu_forma_de_pago, 2)
                        if forma_de_pago == 2:
                            patente = pedir_patente()
                            patente_nueva = definir_patente_nueva(patente)

                        actualizar_contadores(vehiculo, forma_de_pago, cant_motos,
                                              cant_autos, cant_camiones, cont_efectivo,
                                              cont_telepeaje, recaudacion_efectivo,
                                              recaudacion_telepeaje)

                        tiempo_final = time.time()
                        diferencia = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial

                elif carga == 2:
                    vehiculos = "Moto", "Auto", "Camion"
                    formas_de_pago = "Efectivo", "Telepeaje"
                    diferencia = 0
                    tiempo_inicial = time.time()
                    while diferencia < 4:
                        contar_pasadas(diferencia, pasadas_primera_hora,
                                        pasadas_segunda_hora,
                                        pasadas_tercera_hora,
                                        pasadas_cuarta_hora)

                        vehiculo = random.choice(vehiculos)
                        forma_de_pago = random.choice(formas_de_pago)

                        aviso_pasada = "{}. Pago con {}. Hora de pasada: {}.".format(vehiculo,
                                                                                                 forma_de_pago,
                                                                                                 str((round(diferencia / 60) + 1)))
                        if forma_de_pago == "Telepeaje":
                            patente = generar_patente()
                            aviso_pasada += "Patente: {}".format(patente)
                            patente_nueva = definir_patente_nueva(patente)

                        print(aviso_pasada)

                        actualizar_contadores(vehiculo, forma_de_pago, cant_motos,
                                              cant_autos, cant_camiones, cont_efectivo,
                                              cont_telepeaje, recaudacion_efectivo,
                                              recaudacion_telepeaje)

                        tiempo_final = time.time()
                        diferencia = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial
                        time.sleep(random.randint(0,1))

                pago_mayor_uso = forma_de_pago_mas_usada(cont_telepeaje, cont_efectivo)
                promedio_pasadas_por_hora = round((cant_autos + cant_motos + cant_camiones) / 4, 2)
                hora_pico = definir_hora_pico(pasadas_primera_hora,
                                              pasadas_segunda_hora,
                                              pasadas_tercera_hora,
                                              pasadas_cuarta_hora)
                recaudacion_total = recaudacion_efectivo + recaudacion_telepeaje
                pases_totales = cant_motos + cant_autos + cant_camiones

                print("Ingrese la siguiente operacion: ")
                opcion = pedir_opcion(menu_principal, 4)

main()```
````

Comment: That's a lot of code

Comment: Please only post the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. No one wants to read through a novel of code.  Also without reading the code you may want to look into the `global` keyword.

Comment: sorry, lines 241, and 209. There I call the function that isnt working

Comment: can't use global keyword, the teacher said we shouldn't @SmartManoj

Comment: @FrancoLacuadri SO does not have line numbers that is why you should only post the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Then u should  use `class`

Comment: If you can't use the `global` keyword, then it is impossible to *reassign* a global name to point to a new object. You can, however, *mutate* an object that a global name refers to. If you don't understand the distinction between reassigning and mutating, then that's the part of Python you need to learn about.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass global vars to functions by parameters. Use **global** keyword.
Here is an example:

```
x = 10
y = 20

def myFunc():
    global x
    x = 3
    y = 2

myFunc()
print(x, y) # output: 3 20
```